# Send POST request from iPhone to rails app hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, ios7, http-post

I am trying to send some POST-Data from an iPhone app:

```
NSString* serverUrl = @"xxx";

NSString* beaconIDPOST = beaconID;
NSString* deviceTokenPOST = finalDeviceToken;

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&beaconID=%@deviceID=%@clientID=%@",
                  beaconIDPOST,deviceTokenPOST,@"0"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverUrl]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

But my rails app always returns HTTP status code 422, so I guess the formatting of my POST request is incorrect.

I tried this curl request too:

```
curl -d "&deviceID=xxx&beaconID=3&clientID=0" http://xxx
```

With the same result.

I have checked my routes and the url, everything is fine. Any ideas how to solve this error?

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Without seeing the api code there isn't a lot I can suggest. Generally a 422 can be fired if some validation is being violated. Again depending on your server code rails apps generally accept posts with data nested under on object (i.e. params[:user][:name]) so you might be trying to create an object using params that aren't correctly formatted.